# Сбиваются кодировки при работе с денвером.

Tags: denwer, utf-8, сервер

Добрый день. Дорогие специалисты, подскажите начинающему, почему может быть такая проблема - я денвер подгружаю сайт, и в нем сразу сбивается кодировка. Тоесть, если я загружаю его на сервер, то все нормально, но в денвере - все русские слова идут в сбтой кодировке. Чем может быть вызвана эта проблема? Это глюки девнвера или еще что-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо в apache сделать кодировку такой, которую вы используете. По умолчанию в денвере стоит win1251.  Вот пути к конфигурационным файлам. http://www.denwer.ru/faq/other.html#h30-14 
Чтобы найти кодировку, в поиске по файлу наберите Add default charset.